# Use user data of the scene in Three JS editor

Tags: three.js

I use threeJS editor online and I don’t know of to use the Scene’s User Data in the different elements’ events. I put a simple property in the JSON object in the “User Data” field of the scene, and I didn’t see in the documentation how to use it in an event of a Box inside the scene, for example.

If anybody could give me a hand, it would be very kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When putting `userData` to a 3D object, you can access the data in the object's `update()` function like so:

```js
console.log( this.userData );
```

If you have custom data on the scene node, you have to select it first. This can be done in various ways. With a flat hierarchy of objects, you can simply do this:

```js
const scene = this.parent;
console.log( scene.userData );
```

Otherwise use a helper function like:

```js
function getScene( object ) {

    if ( object.parent === null ) return object;
    
    return getScene( object.parent );

}
```